# Pullback of a scheme along the Frobenius morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Let $S$ be an $\mathbb{F}_p$-scheme for a given prime $p$. Let $X$ be a scheme over $S$. Then, we can consider the Frobenius morphism of $X$ relative to $S$, defined by taking the unique morphism given by universal property from $X$ to $X^{(p)}:=X\times_{S,\phi} S$, where $\phi$ is the absolute Frobenius of $S$. Now, if we have another scheme $Y$, over $X^{(p)}$, and we consider its base change along Frobenius, this defines a scheme $Y\times_{X^{(p)}}X$, and a morphism $\psi:Y\times_{X^{(p)}}X\rightarrow Y$. Is it true that $Y\cong (Y\times_{X^{(p)}}X)^{(p)}$ and that the morphism $\psi$ is the Frobenius of $Y\times_{X^{(p)}}X$ relative to $S$? Thank you for any kind of suggestion!

Comment: What is the morphism $X\to X^{(p)}$?

Comment: It's the Frobenius morphism. You start with $X$ over $S$, where $S$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-scheme. You take the absolute Frobenius over $S$, i.e. the morphism which is the identity on the topological space and sends $x$ to $x^p$ on sections. Then you pullback $X$ over $S$ along this absolute Frobenius. This defines $X^{(p)}$. Then you show that there are two maps, one is the absolute Frobenius over $X$ and the other one is the structure morphism over $S$ which makes the pullback diagram commute. This, via universal property, induces a unique map $X\rightarrow X^{(p)}$, which is the relative Frob

Answer (score 0):

No, this is false.

Counterexample 1: Take $S = X$. In this case, the relative Frobenius $X \rightarrow X^{(p)}$ is an isomorphism. Let $Y$ be any $S$-scheme such that the relative Frobenius $Y \rightarrow Y^{(p)}$ is not an isomorphism (e.g. $S = \mathbb{F}_p$ and $Y = \mathbb{A}^1$).

Counterexample 2: Take $S = \mathrm{Spec}~\mathbb{F}_p$ and let $X = \mathbb{A}^1$. We can identify $X^{(p)}$ with $X$, and the relative Frobenius $X \rightarrow X^{(p)}$ is induced by the ring map $\mathbb{F}_p[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ given by $x \mapsto x^p$. Let $Y$ be any $S$-point of $X^{(p)}$. The fiber product $Y \times_{X^{(p)}} X$ is non-reduced, so your map $\psi$ is not an isomorphism. It thus cannot coincide with the relative Frobenius $Y \rightarrow Y^{(p)}$ (which is an isomorphism).